# Embedded Document in symfony2 / MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, symfony, doctrine-orm

I know how to store a simple `Product` Object in **mongodb** using **symfony2**:

This YAML file :

```
Acme\StoreBundle\Document\Product:
    fields:
        id:
            id:  true
        name:
            type: string
        price:
            type: float
```

Will produce this collection :

```
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("..."), 
"name" : "...", 
"price" : "..." 
}
```

But now, I would like to know how to write something generating a structure like that :

```
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("..."), 
"name" : "...", 
"price" : 
   { 
     "before" : "...", 
     "after" : "..." 
   }
}
```

Any idea or documentation link ?

Comment: +1 to compensate random downvote

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an embed document. http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/latest/tutorials/getting-started.html

```
Acme\StoreBundle\Document\Product:
    fields:
        id:
            id:  true
        name:
            type: string
        referenceOne:
            price:
               targetDocument: Acme\StoreBundle\Documents\price
               cascade: all

Acme\StoreBundle\Documents\price:
    fields:
        before:
            type: float
        after:
            type: float
```